# How could I call a value from a list that is within another list (python)?

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to separate a piece of text into sentences and separate those sentences into lists of words. The key point is that I can access each sentence independently and from each sentence access all of the words.

An example of what kind of code I was going for here is:

```
listA = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
listB = ["w","o","r","l","d"]
superList = [listA,listB]
print(superList[0[1]])
```

I create 3 lists: listA, listB and superList. superList contains both lists. I want to access the second letter of the first list. Obviously this attempt of accessing the data in the print command did not work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Obviously you didn't read any manual. Do it!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the second letter this way:

```
print(superList[0][1])

e
```